# Closed Convex Subsets of $\Bbb R^2$; Find them all!

Tags: general-topology

I'm sorry if I put this in the wrong area, the author has a strange habit of going on tangents.
This is Question 66 in chapter 2 of Pugh's Real Analysis.

> Find all the closed and convex subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ up to homeomorphism. 
>   There are nine.

I suspect I have 5: $$\varnothing,   \Bbb R^2, \{a\}, [a, b]$$ and the inclusive unit ball.
Can anyone help me with the rest?

Comment: Also see: [Closed Convex sets of $ \mathbb{R}^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331034/closed-convex-sets-of-mathbbr2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the other four examples are:

1. The closed upper-half plane $ \mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty) $.
2. The line $ \mathbb{R} \times \{ 0 \} $.
3. The line $ [0,\infty) \times \{ 0 \} $.
4. The infinite strip $ [-1,1] \times \mathbb{R} $.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the other four are unbounded.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that [a, b] is not homeomorphic to (-infinity, infinity).