# something about convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

- Let $M$ be a convex subset in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\partial M=\emptyset$. Then $M=\emptyset$ or $\mathbb R^n$.

This can be deduced by

*Theorem* Let $M\subset X$ with $\partial M=\emptyset$ and $X$ is a connected topological space. Then $M=\emptyset$ or $X$.

- Let $M$ be a compact convex subset in $\mathbb R^n$. Then there is a homeomorphism $f:(M,\partial M)\rightarrow(\mathbb D^n,\mathbb S^{n-1})$.

There is a proof in *Lee's An Introduction on Topological Manifold*.

---

My question arises from two facts above. Now I am considering the noncompact case. That is to say, assume that $M$ is a noncompact convex set in $\mathbb R^n$ with boundary. I guess in this situation, there is a homeomorphim $f:(M,\partial M)\rightarrow(\mathbb H^n,\mathbb R^{n-1})$. So can someone help me prove or disprove my guess? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $M=[0,1] \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is convex but $\partial M$ is not connected.

Comment: May be of interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331034/closed-convex-sets-of-mathbbr2

Comment: @Seirios Thank you. So is there any classification theory in higher dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is answered in Berger's book, *Geometry I*.

> **Proposition 11.3.1:** Let $X$ be a $d$-dimensional affine space and $A$ a $d$-dimensional convex subset of $X$. Then $\overset{\circ}{A}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d$.
>
> **Proposition 11.3.8:** Let $A$ be a convex subset of $X$ such that $\dim A = \dim X =d$ and $\mathrm{Fr}(A) \neq \emptyset$. Then $\mathrm{Fr}(A)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ or $S^{d-r-1} \times \mathbb{R}^r$ ($0 \leq r \leq d-1$).